# Can you be awarded the 100th capture XP bonus multiple times?

Tags: pokemon-go

When you catch the 100th pokemon of a species, you get 100 xp points bonus.

[image]

Is this for the **first** 100 or each 100 pokemon captured?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the possible catch bonuses and how much experience do they reward?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272677/what-are-the-possible-catch-bonuses-and-how-much-experience-do-they-reward)

Comment: I was going to consider this a duplicate, but the user asks if you receive the bonus for every 100 caught and not what the different XP bonuses are. Although the answer is in that question, is it really a duplicate?

Comment: Based on similar questions to this one that have been marked and closed as dupes, I don't see why this one shouldn't. See [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286848/100-bonus-xp-where-does-it-come-from), for example.

Comment: I won't mark it as dupe because the question isn't the same at all. (Same in the link you provided). Yes, the post linked has the answer. But the question isn't the same. So the question (what we are voting on) isn't a duplicate. Providing a link to that question is a good approach, but closing it isn't in my opinion.

Comment: To a certain extent... We might as well post questions as "What is X game ?" post everything we know about the game and close all the other questions about that game because they are answered in the "What is X ?" question.

Comment: There is a [meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213976) on the SE Meta site about whether questions like this should be closed as duplicate or not. Unfortunately it doesn't look like there is a general consensus; both sides have good arguments. The [official meta rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844) don't offer much clarification - it only says that questions with similar answers "may" be dupes.

Comment: Where did you get this image? The XP ranges for prestiging/attacking a gym are completely wrong.

Comment: @jdero here [silphroad XP](https://thesilphroad.com/research)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272797/163757):

> This bonus is conferred on every 100th catch of a specific type of Pokemon. This bonus may be repeated.

Yes you can earn this bonus multiple times.

For further proof, [other people](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4t5wvt/bonus_exp_from_captures/?client=ms-android-att-us) are reporting that on their 300th capture they receive the bonus as well.

Comment: Can confirm, I get it for every multiple of 100